# How _CTServerConnectionStartCellTracking works?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-privateapi, cellular-network, cellid

I'm trying to use a private API to retrieve radio cell information.

Since iOS 8.3, the old API doesn't work anymore. So, I'm trying to find another one. I found this method:

> _CTServerConnectionStartCellTracking

Apparently, there are CFStringRef keys for

> _kCTCellTrackedCI, _kCTCellTrackedLAC, _kCTCellTrackedMCC and _kCTCellTrackedMNC

But I don't know how to use them. I think that the first parameter should be a CTServerConnectionRef, but I have no idea for the others.

Do you have any further information?

Thank you :)